# Basis for that $T: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ is in rational canonical form

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations, multilinear-algebra, canonical-transformation

Let $T: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be a linear transformation such that

$T(x,y,z)  = (x+y+z, x+y+z, x+y+z)$

Find a basis for $T$ such that your matrix$(A_T)$ is in rational canonical form.

I know  since $\textit{Dummit and foot}$-$theorem.14$ - pag 476 that exist a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $A_T$ is in ratinal canonical form, but I don't know  a method for find this basis.

Comment: take a look at https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=jordandecomposition+%7B%7B1,1,1%7D,%7B1,1,1%7D,%7B1,1,1%7D%7D

Answer (score 0):

The vectors $(1,1,1)^T$, $(1,-1,0)^T$, $(0,1,-1)^T$ are eigenvectors and form a basis, so the matrix of $T$ will be diagonal in this basis.